# pyHook hooks are making inputs too laggy - is there a way to optimize those hooks?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyhook

I am trying to get inputs when I am playing the game (Warcraft III to be exact). Due to it being an RTS game it requires a high number of inputs in short periods. I am trying to use pyWinhook to get the inputs, mss to get screenshots and cv for image processing.

I have tried disabling image processing just after getting inputs to decrease the amount of work for the script. Nonetheless, it doesn't make much difference. I have also tried to decrease graphic details in-game - no difference also.

I am suspecting that thread is throttling due to high amount of inputs, and not very good hardware on which it's used (I am working at Lenovo X240 with 4GB of RAM).

```py
import os

import cv2
import mss
import numpy as np
import pyWinhook as pyHook
import pythoncom


def main():
    # file names for training data arrays
    file_name = 'training_data.npy'
    copy_file_name = 'training_data_copy.npy'

    # deciding if previous file with data is saved. If yes, it is opened. If not it's created
    if os.path.isfile(file_name):
        print('File exists, loading previous data!')
        print(os.path.realpath(file_name))
        training_data = list(np.load(file_name, allow_pickle=True))
        np.save(copy_file_name, training_data)
    else:
        print('File does not exist, starting fresh!')
        training_data = []

    # getting screenshot and processing it for optimal machine learning processing
    def get_screen():
        with mss.mss() as sct:
            screen = np.array(sct.grab((0, 0, 1366, 768)))
        screen = cv2.cvtColor(screen, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        screen = cv2.resize(screen, (136, 76))
        return screen

    # saving data after acquiring 2500 sets of inputs and screenshots
    def save_data(screen, output):
        training_data.append([screen, output])
        if len(training_data) % 2500 == 0:
            print(len(training_data))
            np.save(file_name, training_data)
        print("Frames taken: " + str(len(training_data)))

    # getting inputs and screen on mouse event
    def OnMouseEvent(event):
        screen = get_screen()
        action = [event.Position, event.Wheel]
        output = action
        save_data(screen, output)
        return True

    # getting inputs and screen on keyboard event
    def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
        screen = get_screen()
        output = event.Key
        save_data(screen, output)
        return True

    # create a hook manager
    hm = pyHook.HookManager()

    # watch for all mouse events
    hm.MouseAll = OnMouseEvent
    hm.KeyUp = OnKeyboardEvent

    # set the hook
    hm.HookMouse()
    hm.HookKeyboard()

    # wait forever
    try:
        pythoncom.PumpMessages()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

    # looping getting data
    while True:
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I want to optimize getting inputs as much as possible because right now inputs in-game are lagging and hanging (which is not proper, because optimal inputs are the basics for machine learning modules).

I am fully aware that it can be an unsolvable problem due to slow hardware and too high amount of inputs per minute, but I want to try anyway.

Comment: You could have a look at [this GTA V](https://pythonprogramming.net/game-frames-open-cv-python-plays-gta-v/) tutorial by sentdex. I think he had the same problem

Comment: I was basing on this tutorial :)

If I remember correctly, there was a problem with getting inputs without focus on terminal. I am getting those, but without needed smoothness. Also, inputs in my case are far more complicated.